# Three address code simulation/parse tree/derivation

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I have a grammar for three address code assignment operation.
[image]

And I have a sample input and output.

[image]

But, I don't understand how the sample output 2nd comes from this grammar. Would anybody give the parse three/derivation?

Comment: Nowhere do you show how the grammar induces the output, so there is no obvious way to approach your question. Could you be more specific about what it is that you don't understand? Is it the fact that the parse tree does not relate variables with corresponding exprs?

Comment: The grammar says you can have one or more vars assigned values from one or more expression statements. I would imagine that from the original parse of an input string that it is verifying the cardinality of both the left and right sides participating in the assignment